# Backbone.syphon handling multiple checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, marionette, backbone-views

Ran into a roadblock with syphon today.

It can't seem to handle serializing the form values into JSON for a specific use case:
a group of checkboxes each carrying a separate value, but all named the same.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="cats" value="Whiskey">
<input type="checkbox" name="cats" value="Tango">
<input type="checkbox" name="cats" value="Cash">
```

I overrode the checkbox reader to give me the value of the checkbox:

```
Backbone.Syphon.InputReaders.register('checkbox', function(el){
        return el.val();  //fetch value not the boolean
    });
```

Now I am getting the last selected value rather than an array of all selected values as expected.

Has anyone dealt with this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a few hours of struggling with this I made a few discoveries:

1. The API documentation and the annotated code base does not match the actual latest code I downloaded. In fact it's quite a bit different.
2. The key (name attribute of the input) is inspected to figure out how to serialize it's data.

So armed with this knowledge I was able to get my checkbox values as an array of values by doing the following 3 things:

1. Register input reader specific for checkbox to return value property.
2. Register checkbox validator to only collect values from checked boxes.
3. Append brackets to name attribute to indicate array input.

.

```
 Backbone.Syphon.InputReaders.register('checkbox', function (el) {
    return el.val();
 });

 Backbone.Syphon.KeyAssignmentValidators.register("checkbox", function ($el, key, value) {
    return $el.prop("checked");
 });

<input type="checkbox" name="cats[]" value="Whiskey">
<input type="checkbox" name="cats[]" value="Tango">
<input type="checkbox" name="cats[]" value="Cash">
```

Comment: totally forgot.. sorry - answer upticked =)

Answer (score 0):

A problem with dbrin's answer is that normal checkboxes (not arrays) get affected by so you get string value **'on'** with checked inputs and boolean value **false** with unchecked inputs. I found this solution:

```
Backbone.Syphon.InputReaders.register('checkbox', function ($el) {
  return ($el.attr('name').endsWith('[]')) ? $el.val() : $el.prop("checked");
});

Backbone.Syphon.KeyAssignmentValidators.register("checkbox", function ($el, key, value) {
  return ($el.attr('name').endsWith('[]')) ? $el.prop("checked") : true;
});
```